# How do I get Facebook and Pinterest to recognize specific images on a page

Tags: images, facebook, meta-tags

I am working on a client site that contains hundreds of pictures.  The would like to show these pictures on Facebook and Pinterest.  My problem is: when they try to put a post on Facebook or Pinterest, these sites only allow them to select the site logo (or another irrelevant image) for the post.  How do I get these sites to recognize meaningful images on a page?  Do I need to use a special class or meta tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook and Pinterest.com both use [The Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) which will look something like:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Example" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/001.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/002.jpg" />
```

You can also find a lot of information on [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph), [Pinterest Developers](https://developers.pinterest.com/rich_pins_article/), [Linkedin Developers](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin), [Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started) and [Google Plus Developers](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/).